# Apache2, folder is not visible, without .htaccess is ok

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

I configured `apache2` server on my local and server, same configuration.

Problem is, that on my local there is not visible folder, where is `.htaccess` file. But on server, with same configuration and `.htaccess` file is everything ok, folder is visible.

Could be problem with `localhost` domain?

Thanks.

Comment: Same Apache version, same configuration (all `*.conf` files from `apache2.conf`/`httpd.conf` to includes including `VirtualHost` configs)
and the same enabled modules? If the folder is accessible without `.htaccess`, but not with `.htaccess`, what's its content? We need a little more information.